# Redirect rule IIS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis, website

We have a linux server which is running our old website for example abcd.com. Now we changed our website and it's being hosted on IIS. for example xyz.com. We have a redirect rule setup on linux server for redirect any queries made to abcd.com to xyz.com .
Problem is now our teams wants to shut off the old server, with linux server down, people who have bookmarked abcd.com goes to site not available because redirect rule is not there. Is there anything we can do so that we can shut down linux server and redirect rule also works?

Comment: Just set up a site abcd.com on IIS, create a redirect reule there and point the DNS of abcd.com to your IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, have a replacement service running prior to retiring the old thing.

Create a web site for the old domains on any hosting you will continue to have. Such as that IIS. Put what you want there, possibly  [HTTP redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) similar to before.

Update DNS for the old domain to point to its new hosting. Test it.

Shut down old web server, decommission host if desired.